# Hive: can't fill index

Tags: hadoop, indexing, hive, hiveql

I'm using Hive 14.0 and have a challenge to index tables. If I want to build an index without *DEFERRED REBUILD*, Hive do not create an index-table for me. If I use it with *DEFERRED REBUILD* an index-table is build, but after *REBUILD* nothing happens. My testtable has myKey as Key from type int. Table is stored as ORC.

```
CREATE INDEX ix_test ON TABLE testtable(myKey) as 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.index.compact.CompactIndexHandler';
```

Nothing happens...

```
CREATE INDEX ix_test ON TABLE testtable(myKey) as 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.index.compact.CompactIndexHandler' WITH DEFERRED REBUILD;
ALTER INDEX ix_test ON testtable REBUILD;
```

See the index table, but it has no data. Tried it with having data in before creating index and load data after creating index (but before using *REBUILD*). Effect is the same.

Look forward that anyone has an idea. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it. The commands are running, but only at hive-shell and not with beeswax. Beeswax ignores the rebuild command.